# Sonarqube - ¿por qué la cobertura "Coverage" es siempre es 0%?

Tags: php, test, sonar

Empecé a utilizar Sonarqube para evaluar mi código hace unos días, sin embargo, no tengo claro de lo que significa "Coverage" y porqué siempre aparece en 0%.
No se si es bueno o malo, o si tenga que configurar algo.
Los manuales en la página de Sonarqube no son muy claros, si alguien me puede orientar, agradecería mucho.

¡Saludos!

[image: Varios proyectos PHP en SonarQube]

Answer (score 3):

### ¿Qué es coverage?

Buenas, el valor de "Coverage" es un medidor de cobertura de código. En tu caso, veo que usas PHP, en el mío, venimos usando C++ y Python para extraer la cobertura de código.

La cobertura de código es una forma de asegurar que las pruebas unitarias que has fabricado han circulado por las líneas de codigo que han "cubierto". Te aseguras que no haces más código que el que las pruebas te permiten, y al mismo tiempo, si tienes que añadir opciones nuevas, no tengas que estar asegurándote que no has roto nada que hayas hecho con anterioridad.

### ¿Cómo se obtiene la cobertura de código?

En primer lugar, necesitas tener pruebas unitarias de tu código y modificar tu código para que las pruebas involucren la menor cantidad de llamadas a tu sistema posible (*Working Effectively with Legacy Code* es un libro muy recomendable para que comiences a hacerlo, aunque no estés usando JAVA, te ofrece ese concepto que pareces necesitar). Esto involucra que modifiques tu forma de hacer código para que enfoques tu esfuerzo en hacer pruebas contra las que enfrentas tu código (las pruebas son la fuente irrefutable de que lo que quieres y lo que haces pueden no ser lo mismo)

Una vez has podido hacer tu primera cobertura de código, tu generador de cobertura de código (que en PHP puede ser phpunit) generará un archivo XML. Pues bien, ese archivo XML se lo tienes que introducir a SonarQube.

### Ya tengo la cobertura de código, ¿cómo se introduce en el proyecto de SonarQube?

- Ve a SonarQube y buscas "Administration".
- Ahí, busca PHP (necesitarás tener el plugin apropiado)
- En PHP, seleccionas PHPunit
- En "Coverage Report" te pone un path al archivo de cobertura de código. También te pone debajo una clave muy curiosa, que en mi versión, pone que es: **sonar.php.coverage.reportPath**
- También tienes, en la parte inferior, otra ubicación donde sitúas el reporte de tests unitarios, la vas a necesitar: **sonar.php.tests.reportPath**

Puedes rellenar manualmente esos valores, que es aceptable con un par de proyectos, pero es inaceptable cuando trabajas montando 25 proyectos, en cuyo caso, desearás ponerlo de una forma "automatizable".

En ese caso, las  o *Keys* que te he remarcado en negrita, te servirán.

Cuando ejecutes el sonar runner, podrás llamar por línea de comandos al sonar runner, como haces con Jenkins o con cualquier otro gestor de CI, y tendrás que ingresarle a la etapa de sonar runner:

```
-Dsonar.php.coverage.reportPath=..\reports\coverage.xml
```

O el directorio donde lo tengas... y listo. Cada vez que ejecutes sonar runner, ya sea por tu CI favorito, o ya sea porque ejecutas el script, tendrás a tu disposición la cobertura de código.

Answer (score 0):

**Coverage** es una métrica de Sonarqube  que  responde a la pregunta de cuanto código de tu proyecto es cubierto por la prueba unitaria que se ejecuta. Por el resultado y la información que  señalas esta claro que no configuraste  tu proyecto para que calcule la métrica por eso te aparece un 0%.

Fuente: [Sonarqube](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions)

Comment: Hi, @bercklyn Carlosviza. Lo que dices es que esta calculando el resto de métricas menos la ce Coverage? y si es asi ¿Dónde dice cómo configurarla?. Saludos¡